# Login Form In Visual Studio 2013 Using Access Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to create a login form in C# Visual Studio 2013 that uses MS Access DB. When I click login button, it shows "Password correct, login successful" regardless of whatever I type in the password section.

Here is the code :

```
    private void signin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String username = user.Text;
        String password = user.Text;
        String temp = null;
        Int32 res = 0;
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AADHARSH\DS\ASP.NET\logindb.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection=conn;
        cmd.CommandText="SELECT Password FROM UserTable WHERE Username='"+username+"'";
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        if(reader.Read())
        {
                result.Text = "Password Correct. Login Succesful";

        }
        else 
        {
            result.Text="Password field cannot be blank";
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and see your data reader has data? And you _never_ use ``password` in your command. That's why it does not matter. You only check your username. Also you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking password against database. Change your query so it uses `"SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE Username=? AND Password=?";` assuming you will use [OleDb parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the contents of TextBoxes which will open your code to SQL injections.

Also, check your code at these lines:

```
 String username = user.Text;
 String password = user.Text;
```

You are using the same textbox value for both username and password, you should probably have `pass.Text` there

Comment: The problem still persists.

Comment: Did you add parameters to your query? Check the @Prasanna's answer. it is a full source code and it looks good, probably copied from somewhere since the table is not the same and TextBoxes don't have your names but everything else looks about right.

Comment: You were right. I used OleDbParameters instead of contents of textboxes. And I changes the String as you said. Build was succesfull.